# Проблема с установкой python kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

```
           File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
       File "/tmp/pip-build-eo0yi09l/kivy/setup.py", line 1073, in <module>
         setup(
       File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 128, in setup
         _install_setup_requires(attrs)
       File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 123, in _install_setup_requires
         dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
       File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 510, in fetch_build_eggs
         resolved_dists = pkg_resources.working_set.resolve(
       File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 772, in resolve
         dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(
       File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1057, in best_match
         return self.obtain(req, installer)
       File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1069, in obtain
         return installer(requirement)
       File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 580, in fetch_build_egg
         return cmd.easy_install(req)
       File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 698, in easy_install
         return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
       File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 724, in install_item
         dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
       File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 909, in install_eggs
         return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
       File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1177, in build_and_install
         self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
       File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1165, in run_setup
         raise DistutilsError("Setup script exited with %s" % (v.args[0],))
     distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status
```

Версия python 3.8.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу ошибаться , но у меня на Python 3.8 была такая же ошибка , по-моему еще не обновили на него Kivy  , рекомендую установить Python 3.7 (имхо).